# Issue with startx saying that there are no monitors found on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, display, arch-linux, xorg, display-driver

I installed Arch on my laptop yesterday and since then I have been unable to open i3. I installed xorg, i3-gaps, and changed my ~/.xinitrc file to read:

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto

exec i3
```

However, I am unable to open i3. Whenever I try to do startx, it gives me an error saying that there is a fatal server error and that no screens are found. Sometimes it says the following:

```
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

But sometimes it doesn't say that and it just hangs after saying there are no screens found.

Here is the error log under /var/log/Xorg.0.log

```
[  1425.899] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[  1425.900]
X.Org X Server 1.20.5
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[  1425.904] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[  1425.905] Current Operating System: Linux mohammed-laptop 5.1.14-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 22 16:28:48 UTC 2019 x86_64
[  1425.905] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=6557ebc3-02f1-4d88-a79d-1afb43df18c7 rw quiet
[  1425.906] Build Date: 30 May 2019  06:44:40PM
[  1425.907]  
[  1425.908] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[  1425.909]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[  1425.909] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[  1425.912] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jun 24 16:48:41 2019
[  1425.913] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[  1425.914] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[  1425.914] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[  1425.914] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[  1425.914] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[  1425.914] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[  1425.914] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[  1425.914] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[  1425.914] (==) Automatically adding devices
[  1425.914] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[  1425.914] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[  1425.914] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[  1425.914] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[  1425.914] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/misc".
[  1425.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1425.914]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/misc").
[  1425.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[  1425.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1425.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[  1425.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1425.914] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[  1425.914]    Entry deleted from font path.
[  1425.914] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[  1425.914] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[  1425.914] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[  1425.914] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[  1425.914] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[  1425.914] (II) Module ABI versions:
[  1425.914]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[  1425.914]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[  1425.914]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[  1425.914]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[  1425.914] (++) using VT number 1

[  1425.915] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[  1425.916] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card1)
[  1425.916] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card1 226:1 fd 10 paused 0
[  1425.917] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[  1425.917] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 11 paused 0
[  1425.919] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:221e rev 6, Mem @ 0xb1400000/4194304, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1425.919] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:11fc:17aa:221e rev 161, Mem @ 0xb0000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[  1425.919] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[  1425.919] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[  1425.919] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[  1425.920] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1425.920]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[  1425.920]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[  1425.920] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[  1425.920] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[  1425.920] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[  1425.920]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[  1425.920]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[  1425.920] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:52:10 CDT 2019
[  1425.920] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[  1425.920] (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 226:1
[  1425.921] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[  1425.921] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[  1425.921] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[  1425.921] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1425.921]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[  1425.921]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1425.921] (II) Loading sub module "wfb"
[  1425.921] (II) LoadModule: "wfb"
[  1425.921] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libwfb.so
[  1425.921] (II) Module wfb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[  1425.921]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[  1425.921]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[  1425.921] (II) Loading sub module "ramdac"
[  1425.921] (II) LoadModule: "ramdac"
[  1425.921] (II) Module "ramdac" already built-in
[  1425.921] (**) NVIDIA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[  1425.921] (==) NVIDIA(0): RGB weight 888
[  1425.921] (==) NVIDIA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[  1425.921] (==) NVIDIA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[  1425.921] (**) NVIDIA(0): Enabling 2D acceleration
[  1425.921] (II) Loading sub module "glxserver_nvidia"
[  1425.921] (II) LoadModule: "glxserver_nvidia"
[  1425.921] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module glxserver_nvidia
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA: Failed to load module "glxserver_nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the GLX module; please check in your X
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     log file that the GLX module has been loaded in your X
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     server, and that the module is the NVIDIA GLX module.  If
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     you continue to encounter problems, Please try
[  1425.921] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     reinstalling the NVIDIA driver.
[  1426.074] (--) NVIDIA(0): Valid display device(s) on GPU-0 at PCI:1:0:0
[  1426.074] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-0
[  1426.074] (--) NVIDIA(0):     DFP-1
[  1426.075] (II) NVIDIA(0): NVIDIA GPU Quadro K2100M (GK106GL) at PCI:1:0:0 (GPU-0)
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(0): Memory: 2097152 kBytes
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(0): VideoBIOS: 80.06.63.00.1a
[  1426.075] (II) NVIDIA(0): Detected PCI Express Link width: 16X
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: disconnected
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: Internal TMDS
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-0: 165.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: disconnected
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: Internal DisplayPort
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0): DFP-1: 960.0 MHz maximum pixel clock
[  1426.075] (--) NVIDIA(GPU-0):
[  1426.075] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failed to assign any connected display devices to X screen 0.
[  1426.075] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     Set AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration if you want the server
[  1426.075] (EE) NVIDIA(0):     to start anyway
[  1426.075] (EE) NVIDIA(0): Failing initialization of X screen
[  1426.107] (II) UnloadModule: "nvidia"
[  1426.107] (II) UnloadSubModule: "wfb"
[  1426.107] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fb"
[  1426.107] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[  1426.107] (EE)
Fatal server error:
[  1426.107] (EE) no screens found(EE)
[  1426.107] (EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.
[  1426.107] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[  1426.107] (EE)
[  1426.117] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

I ran xrandr, but it told me that it can't open display. I assumed that this might be because xorg did not autoconfigure so I reinstalled it, but that still did not work. So I added:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier             "Screen0"
    Driver                 "nouveau"
    BusID                  "PCI:0:12:0"
EndSection
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier             "dummy_monitor"
    HorizSync              28.0-80.0
    VertRefresh            60.0
    Modeline               "1920x1080" 172.80 1920 2040 2248 2576 1080 1081 1084 1118
EndSection
```

Then I was given a different error saying "failed to set IOPL for I/O (operation not permitted)" before the same erorr about no screens being found and the log file was in a different location. This time it said the following:

```
[   240.358] (WW) Failed to open protocol names file lib/xorg/protocol.txt
[   240.358] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.5
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   240.359] Build Operating System: Linux Arch Linux
[   240.360] Current Operating System: Linux mohammed-laptop 5.1.14-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 22 16:28:48 UTC 2019 x86_64
[   240.360] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/vmlinuz-linux root=UUID=6557ebc3-02f1-4d88-a79d-1afb43df18c7 rw quiet
[   240.361] Build Date: 30 May 2019  06:44:40PM
[   240.361]  
[   240.362] Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
[   240.363]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   240.363] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   240.365] (==) Log file: "/home/mohammed/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log", Time: Mon Jun 24 19:08:52 2019
[   240.366] (==) Using config file: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf"
[   240.367] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   240.367] (==) ServerLayout "Layout0"
[   240.367] (**) |-->Screen "Screen0" (0)
[   240.367] (**) |   |-->Monitor "Monitor0"
[   240.367] (**) |   |-->Device "Device0"
[   240.367] (**) |   |-->GPUDevice "Device0"
[   240.367] (**) |-->Input Device "Keyboard0"
[   240.367] (**) |-->Input Device "Mouse0"
[   240.367] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   240.367] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   240.367] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[   240.367] (==) Automatically binding GPU devices
[   240.367] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[   240.367] (WW) `fonts.dir' not found (or not valid) in "/usr/share/fonts/misc".
[   240.367]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   240.367]    (Run 'mkfontdir' on "/usr/share/fonts/misc").
[   240.367] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/TTF" does not exist.
[   240.367]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   240.367] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/OTF" does not exist.
[   240.367]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   240.367] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/Type1" does not exist.
[   240.367]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   240.367] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/75dpi
[   240.367] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   240.367] (WW) Hotplugging is on, devices using drivers 'kbd', 'mouse' or 'vmmouse' will be disabled.
[   240.367] (WW) Disabling Keyboard0
[   240.367] (WW) Disabling Mouse0
[   240.367] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   240.367]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   240.367]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[   240.367]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[   240.367]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[   240.368] (++) using VT number 1

[   240.369] (II) systemd-logind: took control of session /org/freedesktop/login1/session/_31
[   240.370] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[   240.371] (II) systemd-logind: got fd for /dev/dri/card0 226:0 fd 10 paused 0
[   240.372] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:221e rev 6, Mem @ 0xb1400000/4194304, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[   240.372] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:11fc:17aa:221e rev 161, Mem @ 0xb0000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
[   240.372] (WW) Open ACPI failed (/var/run/acpid.socket) (No such file or directory)
[   240.372] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   240.372] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   240.373] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   240.373]    compiled for 1.20.5, module version = 1.0.0
[   240.373]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[   240.373] (II) LoadModule: "nvidia"
[   240.373] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/nvidia_drv.so
[   240.374] (II) Module nvidia: vendor="NVIDIA Corporation"
[   240.374]    compiled for 1.6.99.901, module version = 1.0.0
[   240.374]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   240.374] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  430.26  Tue Jun  4 17:52:10 CDT 2019
[   240.374] (II) NVIDIA Unified Driver for all Supported NVIDIA GPUs
[   240.374] xf86EnableIOPorts: failed to set IOPL for I/O (Operation not permitted)
[   240.374] (EE) No devices detected.
[   240.374] (EE) 
Fatal server error:
[   240.374] (EE) no screens found(EE) 
[   240.374] (EE) 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   240.374] (EE) Please also check the log file at "/home/mohammed/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   240.374] (EE) 
[   240.397] (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is due to the fact that `X` identifies **two** cards in (obviously) 2 different slots. The reason you appear to get different results is that `X` probe(s) are choosing one, or the other card.

There are a couple different directions you could take;

- remove (comment) the slot you've chosen, and see if `X`[1]
  chooses the card probed with an active port (connected to you monitor)
- comment the slot you have in your config, and declare the other one

This is the entry from your log that indicates what I'm talking about

```
[  1425.919] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 8086:0416:17aa:221e rev 6, Mem @ 0xb1400000/4194304, 0xa0000000/268435456, I/O @ 0x00005000/64, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[  1425.919] (--) PCI: (1@0:0:0) 10de:11fc:17aa:221e rev 161, Mem @ 0xb0000000/16777216, 0x80000000/268435456, 0x90000000/33554432, I/O @ 0x00004000/128, BIOS @ 0x????????/524288
```

Lastly, you should try to put as little as possible into your conf file. As `X` has gotten pretty good at making all the right choices.

IOW Only make additions, when the results aren't as desired. :)

1) before

```
    BusID                  "PCI:0:12:0"
```

after

```
#    BusID                  "PCI:0:12:0"
```

Comment: " remove (comment) the slot you've chosen, and see if `X`
  chooses the card probed with an active port (connected to you monitor)"

Comment: What do you mean by that? Are you referring to what I added about devices in the config file?

Comment: I've updated my reply in hopes it makes more sense to you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You've configured Xorg to use *nouveau*, but your startup logs show that it is trying to use the proprietary *nvidia* driver. You can't mix the two.

Uninstall the *nvidia* driver completely, remove all your Xorg configuration, then try again. (If you use nvidia, it will provide its own configuration. If you use nouveau, Xorg will automatically detect devices without any manual configuration.)

Comment: Could I alternatively just change nouveau to Nvidia if I want to run the proprietary drivers?